# SAS Do Whitlock Loop

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and this is the question I need answer to. Thought I'd post the entire question to help you people better understand my question.

Part of a hematology data is given. Calculate change from baseline for each visit (Baseline is defined as the last non missing pre dose measurement). 
a.Using baseline subsetting and merging.
b.Using a Do Whitlock group.
Change from baseline will be presented for post dose measurements only.

```
data hemo;
length visit $12 param $12;
input subjid visit $ param $ value ;
cards;
101 Screening    Haemoglobin 12.6
101 Visit1       Haemoglobin .
101 Visit2(Dose) Haemoglobin 12.7
101 Visit3       Haemoglobin 8.6
102 Screening    Haemoglobin 11.6
102 Visit1       Haemoglobin 11.5
102 Visit2(Dose) Haemoglobin 10.4
102 Visit3       Haemoglobin 11.5
103 Screening    Haemoglobin .
103 Visit1       Haemoglobin 10.5
103 Visit2(Dose) Haemoglobin 11.2
103 Visit3       Haemoglobin 12.1
;
run;
```

I need help doing it with the do Whitlock loop. So far, I've this(which is actually nothing :D)

```
data q4b;
retain subjid visit param value change;
do i =1 by 1 until (last.subjid);
    set hemo;
    by subjid;
    if value ne . then change = change - value;
    output;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sas datasteps automatically loops over observations of the `set MyDataset;` so you do not need to loop.
What you need to retain is the baseline and an indicator that the baseline has been found and no longer needs updating (last instruction in the datastep). Baseline and the indicator need to be reset when the firsto obs for a subject is found.
The function index gives you the position of the string you are looking for if found, 0 otherwise.

```
data change;
    set hemo;
    by subjid;
    retain Baseline BaselineFound;
    if first.subjid then do;
        Baseline=.;
        BaselineFound=0;
    end;
    if index(visit,"Dose") then BaselineFound=1;
    if BaselineFound=1 and index(visit,"Dose")=0 then change=value-Baseline;
    if BaselineFound=0 and value>. then Baseline=value;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful but not the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Without DoW (Do Whitloop):
(all visits)

```
data change;
    set hemo;
    by subjid;
    retain baseline;
    if (first.subjid) then baseline=.;
    change = value - baseline;
    output;
    if value ne . then baseline = value;
run;
```

With DoW:
(only last visit)

```
data change (drop=base); 
    do until (last.subjid); 
        set hemo; 
        by subjid;
        change = value - base;
        baseline = base;
        if value ne . then base = value; 
    end; 
run;
```

(See this [paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi28/099-28.pdf) for details)

---

EDIT: I add another example to clarify the retain/output mechanism.

```
data test;
    do i=1 to 10;
        output;
    end;
run;
data test;
    set test;
    retain j;
    output;
    j=i;
run;
```

Here you have i from 1 to 10. The variable j is computed **after** the output statement, so its value (=i) is not printed in the same data cycle in which it's set.

Usually its value would be forgotten but the retain statement makes SAS remember it from one cycle to the next, where it gets printed in the output dataset.
The result is a scaled i-j couple:

```
i j
---
1 .
2 1
3 2
```

Comment: You just made my day easy, Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I'm having difficulty in understanding this line after the output statement.

    if value ne . then baseline = value;

I'm not much familiar with the inner working of SAS, Why/How does it read the value from the previous observation and write into the base of next observation?

Well, My assumumption is that since it came after ouput statement, it should read from the next osbersation also

Comment: There are two direct ways to bring a value from one row to the next. One is the lag() function, the other the retain statement. This last keeps the value of the retained variable until this is overwritten. You can try putting the output after that line you quote. The output statement writes the line into the output dataset, the last line has its effect in the next data step cycle (i.e. overwrites the last valid base value for use into the next row).

Comment: Sorry, but still not clear. since "if value ne . then baseline = value;" came after "output;", you said it has the effect in the next data step cycle, but it read the varaible named "value" from the previous observation instead of the next observation. why?

Comment: Thank you. Things make much sense now.